# Javascript change style of td element using tr id

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have one table:

```
<table>
    <tr id="436">
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I need using Javascript to get tr element using id and then in that tr add CSS style of changing text color.

I have try `getelementbyid("436")` but I don't know how to do next.

So I need to get this:

```
  <table>
    <tr id="436">
       <td style="color: red">1</td>
       <td style="color: red">2</td>
       <td style="color: red">3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this, if you really want to change the color of the `td` elements:

```
var tr = document.getElementById("436");
var tds = tr.getElementsByTagName("td");

for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
   tds[i].style.color="red";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UEbCL/

Comment: changing the color property of tr will be applied to td also i think no need for this

Comment: true, but this way the DOM is modified the exact same way as his given result should look like.

Comment: yes but the dom will look like this: `<table>
    <tr id="436" style="color:red">
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>` and not like the result he wanted to have

Comment: yes you are right in that way sorry i was misunderstand you :)

Comment: thank You...Your code works very nice...:) I was expecting that this is not possible..but now...i see that it really works...thank You again.

Answer (score 1):

it should be something like this:

```
 document.getElementById("436").style.color="red"
```

Comment: this changes the color of the `tr` element, not of all the `td` elements inside `tr`

Comment: And what ? changing the color of `tr` will applied to `td` also

Comment: i need to change only color of tr because i have 7rows on one line, three rows are text read from mysql database and others 4 are images(when user click on image it downloads channel list for that platform - dvbviewer, progdvb, altdvb etc). i im making admin portal.